# Want to setup acl but my /etc/fstab does not look like the docs

Tags: permissions, fstab, acl

I am trying to install an ACL on an ubuntu 14 box. My /etc/fstab file does not look exactly like the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) and I would like some advice on how to proceed. here is my config.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/vda1 during installation
UUID=050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Where do I put the acl? After errors=remount-ro? Just want to check that I am implementing this very low level stop correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `fstab` is:

```
device    mount-point    type    options    fs_freq    fs_passno
```

(or, as you can see in the header comments:)

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
```

In this case they are asking you to add `acl` to the options, and the options in the example are `defaults`, whereas for you they are `errors=remount-ro`.
So, yes, you can add the `acl` after `errors=remount-ro`:

```
UUID=050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro,acl 0       1
```